# помогите ошибка на строчке 1921 хотя в коде 100 строчек

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, score, color): 
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.score = score
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts =[-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x= starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and \
                    pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                        self.x += self.paddle.x
                        self.score.hit()
                        return True
            return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3


        
            
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0, 100,10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0

        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.started = False
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>',self.turn_right)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>',self.start_game)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<r>',self.replay)

        
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
            
    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def start_game(self,evt):
        self.started = True

    def replay():
         ball.hit_bottom == False
         paddle.started == False
         self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)



class Score:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
     self.score = 0
     self.canvas = canvas
     self.id = canvas.create_text(450, 10, text='score %s'  % (self.score), \
         fill=color)
     
    def hit(self):
         self.score += 1
         self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text=self.score)
     
tk=Tk()
tk.title("pocket tenis alfa")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

score = Score(canvas, 'orange')
paddle = Paddle(canvas,  'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, score, 'red')

game_over_tex = canvas.create_text(260, 210,text='GAME OVER', fill = 'light blue', state='hidden', font = ('Helvetica', 28))
game_over_te = canvas.create_text(240, 190,text='GAME OVER', fill = 'red', state='hidden', font = ('Helvetica', 28))
game_over_text = canvas.create_text(250, 200,text='GAME OVER', fill = 'black', state='hidden', font = ('Helvetica', 28))

 

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False and paddle.started == True:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    if ball.hit_bottom == True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        canvas.itemconfig(game_over_text, state='normal')

        canvas.itemconfig(game_over_tex, state='normal')

        canvas.itemconfig(game_over_te, state='normal')

    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

> ошибка:>вот ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Gadjet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
    TypeError: Paddle.replay() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Comment: Ошибка вроде как возникает не в вашем коде (в коде библиотеки), но по причине вашего кода. У вас метод replay без аргументов, хотя подразумевается что они должны там быть (как и в start_game и прочих что вы передаете в bind_all)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает не у вас в коде, а у тех, кто писал библиотеку `Tkinter`, на строке **1921**. У вас написана функция `replay` без аргументов, хотя они должны быть

Answer (score 0):

Причина в функции. Ошибка `TypeError: Paddle.replay() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given` говорит, что у этой функции ожидается 0 позиционных аргументов (т.е. в у нее вообще не объявлены атрибуты), а при ее вызове в нее передали 2 аргумента

Теперь посмотрите в функцию:

```
    def replay():
         ball.hit_bottom == False
         paddle.started == False
         self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
```

Я вижу тут 3 проблемы:

- Отсутствие аргументов `self` (это ведь метод класса) и `evt` (см. в аналогичные методы, использованные в `self.canvas.bind_all`)
- Работа с `ball.hit_bottom` и `paddle.started`. Скорее всего, тут нужно убрать сравнение и оставить присваивание
- Непонятно откуда берутся переменные `ball` и `paddle`. Скорее всего, тут будет ошибка. Вам нужно их в объект `Paddle` передавать, чтобы он мог с ними работать в своих методах

Итого:

```
    def replay(self, evt):
        ball.hit_bottom = False
        paddle.started = False
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
```